# How to upload files/images

Tags: support, attachment

If I have a file that I want to reference or put up to ask a question on how would I do that? Bearing in mind that I'm a new user.

Comment: What kind of a file?

Comment: Files such as doc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We don't host files, and I would strongly discourage any questions that require you to reference uploaded files elsewhere. You're better off distilling your question down to a [minimal example](http://s.tk/mcve).

For images, you *can* upload them but until you gain at least 10 reputation you won't be able to include them inline. Just click the image button (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>):

[image: image button in editor]

...and follow the prompts until you get a bit of Markdown that looks like this...

```
![enter image description here][2]
```

Then remove the exclamation point so that you can post it (once you're no longer [a new user](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user), you can skip this step).

Comment: LOL in that case next question is how do I get/earn reputations

Comment: By posting good, useful questions and answers!

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=how+to+earn+reputation

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation

Answer (score -3):

Stack Overflow does not allow file uploads apart from images. If you really want to upload files, used a file sharing service like Dropbox or Google Drive and post the links in your question.

Comment: This is already answered by Shog, year ago. No need to repeat.

Comment: And it is bad advice as well. We don't want questions that point to dead content.